# ¿Como crear inputbox en MFC DLL C++?

Tags: c++

Cordial saludo compañeros, resulta que estoy desarrollando un MFC DLL que lo va a leer una aplicación, lo que necesito saber es, si es posible generar inputbox en MFC DLL C++, para que el usuario por teclado le ingrese el valor a cierto tipo de variables.estoy trabajandolo en MS Visual Studio 2017 ¿Como podria hacerlo?

Comment: si quieres hacer un I/O de datos, no podrás al menos que crees una ventana, para ahorrarte eso, puedes abrir una consola con `AllocConsole();` y cada ves que el modulo sea cargado, se abrirá una consola el cual puedes controlarla leyendo la API en msdn...

Comment: Estoy intentando usarla pero no me permite ingresar nada, podrías ilustrarme como podría usar esa consola para guardar el valor de una variable por teclado.

Comment: tanto numérica como carácter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543571/allocconsole-not-displaying-cout